# How to use preprocessor symbols in PyCUDA?

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

There is a program written in C with some CUDA kernels and I need to adapt this program to run in python using PyCUDA. Now, in this C code there are some global variables defined and some of those kernels are accessing those variables via #ifdef. What I would like to do is to define those global variables in python and then just copy my CUDA C kernels code and run them using SourceModule scheme (let's say I'm just lazy). I imagine something like this:

```
my_global_var=True
mod=SourceModule(""" __global__ void func() {
...
#ifdef my_global_var
do something
#endif }
""")
```

Is there any way to do that? Clearly, that naive attempt doesn't work at all. Should I use some kind of special pointer or something like that? 
In other words, what exacly happens when CUDA C kernel compiled with PyCUDA have #ifdef in it?

**Edit:** 
Well, it is possible that I'm misusing the "global variable" term here. The C code looks more or less like this:

```
#define X
__global__ void func(...) {
...
#ifdef X
do something
#endif }
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to use that C code in PyCUDA without messing with it too much. So I would like to just copy "**global_** void func...", put it in PyCUDA SourceModule and define that X (no matters if it is global variable or something different) in python (like in the first pseudocode). Is it possible?

Comment: Could you clarify what you are actually try to do here, maybe with a slightly more fleshed out example? In the CUDA code you have shown, `my_global_var` is a preprocessor symbol, not a global variable (that has a particular meaning in the context of CUDA code). What you have written doesn't much sense at the moment

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I edited the main post, I hope it is more understandable now.

Comment: So you want to be able to control the setting of preprocessor symbols during JIT compilation using PyCUDA's SourceModule?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, yes.

Comment: @talonmies Oh, I think I get it now! So basically what I can do is to define my variable X in python and then write (in python) something like if X=True: then string+="do something" (where string is my C kernel code)? Then just do SourceModule(string). That should do something similar to what is happening in the C code, right?

Comment: that would one be one approach to generate conditional compilation of source code at run time (usually called metaprogramming), but it isn't what you were asking about, I think, and it isn't a good solution to your problem.

Comment: Well, that would indeed require messing with the C code - which was something I wanted to avoid. Do you have any other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with compiling any C or C++ code, external manipulation of preprocessor symbols (by which I mean outside of the code itself) requires passing additional arguments to the compiler. If you had this code:

```
__global__ void func(...) {
...
#ifdef X
do something
#endif 

}
```

then the way to set `X` during compilation would be to pass `-DX` to the compiler, which defines the symbol `X` during the current preprocessor pass.

You can do exactly the same thing in PyCUDA by passing options to the build using the `options` keyword in the `SourceModule` constructor. Compiler options are passed as a list, so your PyCUDA example could be implemented something like this:

```
my_global_var=True

....

build_options = []
if my_global_var:
    build_options.append('-Dmy_global_var')

mod=SourceModule(""" __global__ void func() {
...
#ifdef my_global_var
do something
#endif }
""", options=build_options)
```

[Disclaimer: Totally untested, use at own risk - I don't have a working PyCUDA installation ATM]

Here, we simply build a list containing as many entries as there are options you need to pass to the compiler, and then instantiate a `SourceModule` instance with those options. After that, it should just work...

Comment: Hey, I've tested it on some simple code and it worked as expected. Any reference sources that I can use if I find myself in need of better understanding what is really happening here? Thanks!

Comment: I am not really sure what you want to understand further, but every is covered in (1) any good book or tutorial on the C preprocessor, (2) the nvcc documentation and (3) the PyCUDA documentation

Comment: OK. It would be probably good to change `if my_global_var` to something like `try` with `except NameError` - since this particular code will raise an error if my_global_var is not defined.